# C# code for windows service is throwing exception during executing ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, oracle, service

While executing the C# code for a windows service the executereader function to read **SELECT** query the code is throwing exception

> "Operation is not valid due to current state of object.

I have used the same code to connect to oracle database in a C# code for windows form. There every thing is fine. I even even used ExecuteNonQuery function but nothing is helping.

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            ccpwrm();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }

        public static void ccpwrm()
        {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("User Id=ISCRMRT;Password=ISCRMRT;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = Level-2-Gateway)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = LEVEL2)))");
            OracleCommand comnd = new OracleCommand();

            con.Open();
            comnd.CommandText = "select * from CCP_BILLET";
            OracleDataReader read = comnd.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\TestServiceLog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                sw.WriteLine(read[0].ToString().TrimEnd());
                sw.WriteLine(read[4].ToString().TrimEnd());
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ccpwrm();
        }

    }
}
```

I want the selected columns from oracle table to be written on file, but the code is always stucking at same point, i.e. `ExecuteReader()` statement.

Comment: just pass `con` to `command`  `OracleCommand comnd = new OracleCommand(con);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is because the OracleCommand is not associated with the OracleConnection.

Try passing the connection in the OracleCommand constructor, or setting the Connection property.

```
OracleCommand comnd = new OracleCommand("select * from CCP_BILLET", con);
```

or

```
comnd.Connection = con;
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand?view=netframework-4.8